# Create a drop down list of many links in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have many links about for example link1, link2, link3, link4 ...link9.
I have to add those links in the drop down. I tried with rails select_tag and also with html tag

**Using html select tag**

```
<span class="device_update">
    <select>
      <option value="link1"><%= link_to "link1", "#",{:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'} %></option>
      <option value="link2"><%= link_to "link2", "#",{:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'} %></option>
      <option value="link3"><%= link_to "link3", "#",{:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'} %></option>
           ......

      <option value="link9"><%= link_to "link9", "#",{:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'} %></option>
        </select>
    </span>
```

How can I make drop down lists of many links

Comment: what does it create? give some additional information

Comment: It creates dropdown list but it doesn't creates links

Comment: You cant use link_tag within option tags.

Comment: @anonymousxxx I don't get it can you specify the example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did this by following way. For this I refer [bootstrap button dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns)

```
<div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Action <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><%= link_to "link1", "#",{:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'} %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "link1", "#",{:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'} %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "link3", "#",{:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'} %></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><%= link_to "link4", "#",{:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'} %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As **@anonymousxxx** said,you can't have a `link_to` or a `hyperlink` inside an `optiontag`.

You better use `jquery slideToggle()` to list the `drop-down` of links

```
<div class="button">click me</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="">link1</a>
    <a href="">link2</a>
    <a href="">link3</a>
    <a href="">link4</a>
</div>
```

And the Jquery code is

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(".dropdown").slideToggle();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pavan28/7WzCg/)**