# Rails Select Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I'm new at this and have searched but haven't been able to find the exact combo of answers I'm looking for.  I'm trying to create a pull down menu which will be supplied by a database column (my code works up to here) and then have each option be a link which will go to the page for the selected city.

```
<%= collection_select(:city_id, 0, City.visible, :id, :name) %>
```

The line above creates the pull down I need filled from my City db column.

Can I then add a link_to in here somewhere?  I've seen people talk about jquery but doesn't Rails have an answer for this?  I'd like the link to go to city/cityName.

Thanks for any help!

Edit - The other link provided doesn't exactly show the data pulled in from the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a drop down list of many links in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708852/create-a-drop-down-list-of-many-links-in-rails)

Comment: are you using simpleform for your forms or regular forms_for?

Comment: Regular form_for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there might be a way to use rails link_to, I've ended up using html_safe in these situations.  Have you tried replacing the "text" value of your collection via html_safe? such as:

```
"<a href=#{show_path_for_object_here}>#{text_of_object_erb here}</a>".html_safe
```

If your routes for cities are standard like:

```
resources :cities
```

Then the actual code will probably be fairly close to:

```
<%= collection_select(:city_id, 0, City.visible, :id, "<a href=cities/#{city.id}>#{city.name}</a>".html_safe) %>
```

Comment: Thank you bkunxi01.  I tried something like this:

`    <% @cities.each do |c| %> 
  <%= collection_select(:city_id, 0, City.visible, :id, "<a href=city/#{c.permalink}>#{c.name}</a>".html_safe) %>
      <% end %>`

But I'm getting an undefined method error because of the url part.  I THINK it's taking the URL to be a method?  This is still fairly new to me.

Comment: I don't believe you should be iterating through each city to call the collection_select since the collection_select method is already getting the contents of its collection from "City.visible".  Also, what does the error say exactly?  Does it say no method 'name' for nil:nilclass or "no method permalink for nil:nilclass" or does it call an error for the whole url?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a way that works perfectly.  I did end up needing to use a bit of JavaScript and forego the Rails select tag.  Either way, I wanted to post what worked really well for me:

```
<select onchange="window.location=this.value">
  <option>Select a City</option>
  <% @cities.each do |c| %> 
    <option value="city/<%= c.permalink %>"><%= c.name %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```